# View not working for taxonomy pages

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I am using the Views module for multiple sections of my site.  I have added a custom view for displaying results of a taxonomy term. The taxonomy term is 'resource-topics'. The view is set up with a path setting '/resource-topics/%'.  I have added a custom template to use for these pages and when I go to the url /resource-topics/all...it uses my custom template, but when I go to an actual taxonomy term, such as /resource-topics/term-name it just shows a random list of content that matches the taxonomy term without using my custom template.  How can I get the taxonomy terms to use my View?

Comment: I want to say it's because the term aliases from path/pathauto are just aliases, and the term router is still taxonomy/term/%. This sounds like a good use case for something like TVI, especially if you are in Drupal 7. https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi

Comment: @Kevin thank for the response.  I installed the TVI module and configured it accordingly.  Now my taxonomy pages redirect to the homepage :( but if I manually type in resource-topics/all...my template is used.  I am completely confusted

Comment: Not sure about the redirects to homepage, but if you clone the taxonomy view and use taxonomy/term/% - then the term pages should respect that when the vocabulary is set to use that view. I have never had much success using any other path. How is the template for resource-topics/all even being picked up? Is that a node page? What is it?

Comment: @Kevin When you say 'clone the taxonomy view', do you mean clone the default view for that taxonomy.  How do I do that?

Comment: Views if I recall comes with a taxonomy term view out of the box. You should enable that, then clone it out - the cloned one will act as the modified View for your vocabularies/terms using that display.